# 0 value and empty cell for scripts on excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PERS0.png)

Hello, i'm not an expert on using VBs.. I've  a question for you.

I'm working on 2 (.csv) files (one of them is a reference).
So, I want to compare the values on the second file with values on the "reference" file by processing the tables on each one (same columns, only some cells values are different)

The problem is that when I've a "O" value in the 'ref' file and an 'empty cell" in the other file, I remark the result of comparison if the same (since, I've understood empty=0 for VBs since any uninitialized variable gets 0 as value.)
and this is the reason my vbs code doesn't make difference between "0" values cells and blank cells..
Well, I'm asking if you could have some suggestions to me.
In my viewpoint, I think it's right to add:

```
 **run_val = "Empty_CELL"**

 **ref_val = "Empty_CELL"**
```

before processing the tables in order to give a default value to cells value, and then, make difference with 0's
but, still, I'm not sure and I don't know if syntax is correct or not.

Can someone offer his valuable opinion?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: http://www9.0zz0.com/2016/06/07/11/782086843.png
thank you

Answer (score 0):

A non-initialized VBScript variable is `Empty`; empty values 'count' as 0 or "" in computations. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```
>> Dim e
>> WScript.Echo CStr(IsEmpty(e)), TypeName(e), CStr(e = Empty)
>> WScript.Echo e + 1 + e
>>
True Empty True
1
```

So use [IsEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to catch empty cell values.

**Update wrt comment**:

I tackled the problem

> The problem is that when I've a "O" value in the 'ref' file and an
>   'empty cell" in the other file, I remark the result of comparison if
>   the same (since, I've understood empty=0 for VBs since any
>   uninitialized variable gets 0 as value.) and this is the reason my vbs
>   code doesn't make difference between "0" values cells and blank
>   cells..

obviously, that's different from

> to make difference between "0" and " "

For that, just look at:

```
type 37673790.vbs
Option Explicit

Dim n : n = 0
Dim s : s = " "
If s = n Then
   WScript.Echo "Surprise"
Else
   WScript.Echo "Not s = n"
End If

cscript 37673790.vbs
Not s = n
```

This

```
>> a = Array(Empty, 0, "", " ")
>> For Each e In a
>>     WScript.Echo CStr(IsEmpty(e))
>> Next
>>
True
False
False
False
```

should stop unbased speculations wrt

> the difference won't be seen in the loop

Update II:

So it's still whether "0 is different than a blank cell" ...

My last attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Array(Empty, 0, "", " ")
Dim i, j
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    For j = 0 To UBound(a)
        WScript.Echo i, j, Cmp(a(i), a(j))
    Next
Next

Function Cmp(a, b)
  If VarType(a) <> VarType(b) Then
     Cmp = "type diff (" & TypeName(a) & "<->" & TypeName(b) & ")"
  Else
     If a = b Then
        Cmp = "val equal"
     Else
        Cmp = "val diff (" & Join( Array(a, b), "|") & ")"
     End If
  End If
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 37673790.vbs
0 0 val equal
0 1 type diff (Empty<->Integer)
0 2 type diff (Empty<->String)
0 3 type diff (Empty<->String)
1 0 type diff (Integer<->Empty)
1 1 val equal
1 2 type diff (Integer<->String)
1 3 type diff (Integer<->String)
2 0 type diff (String<->Empty)
2 1 type diff (String<->Integer)
2 2 val equal
2 3 val diff (| )
3 0 type diff (String<->Empty)
3 1 type diff (String<->Integer)
3 2 val diff ( |)
3 3 val equal
```

Comment: But, In my case, I'm looking to make difference between "0" and " "  
If I use is @Empty, the difference won't be seen in the loop.
So, I think, change should happen before processing the tables by giving default values to all cells and then to compare.

If I use IsEmpty(), I will catch empty cell values, but also "0" values.. and it's not the purpose..

Comment: Thanks alot..
I understand what you're talking about, but it seems we are not talking about the same issue.

My issue is that, when my code begins processing my 2 excel files to see if there is any difference between its cells value, It doesn't recognize that 0 is different than a blank cell..
My problem is to know what to add so as the difference could be noticed..

For two files, and to two cells to compare for example (A12), if the cell 'A12' of the ref file is "0" and 'A12" for the other file is a blank cell..then, I want to notice it's an error 'report log'
http://urlz.fr/3GCc